# Facebook 'Facepile' won't implement

Tags: facebook, wordpress, html, iframe

How do I implement facebook's 'Facepile' plug-in; everytime I try to do so; rather through a WP plugin, HTML5, or iFrame - it displays ***nothing***.

I have my current attempt, implemented as an iFrame within the right side bar at the link below:

http://tinyurl.com/3bynyvp

You'll notice it begans to load in place, then stops, moves all the way to the bottom of the content of the blog; and displays only the widget title.

The iFrame was inserted within a 'PHP code' sidebar widget.

The exact iFrame code generated via FB developer;

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FMax-Brooks%2F60684688791&amp;size=small&amp;width=260&amp;max_rows=3&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:260px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And here's a fiddle setup with the HTML5 code; http://jsfiddle.net/cam77/a97Tj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facepile developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) contains complete implementation details. Also on the site:

> **Why is nothing displaying?**
>
> The plugin only displays friends' photos. If the user does not have
>   friends who have liked your page or have connected to your site, no
>   faces will be shown.
>
> If you are displaying users who have liked your page and no users
>   have liked it yet, the plugin will render nothing. If some users have
>   liked your page, but none of the viewing users friends have liked it,
>   the plugin will display the total number of users who have liked your
>   page.
>
> If you are displaying users who have connected to your site and none
>   of the users friends have connected yet, the plugin will render
>   nothing.

Comment: Thanks; Yea I've read that. It doesn't apply as there are friends attached that have liked the page I used. I edited the question above.